# How to open new activity (or dialog or link) from a Infowindow - Google Maps v2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

I want to open a new activity (or a custom dialog or a link) from a infowindow. I want my UI works in this way:
1) I see the map
2) I click on a marker to show an Infowindow
3) I click a button (or something else) into the Infowindow to open a new activity (or a dialog) to show more information. Alternatively, I click a link into the Infowindow to open a webpage to show more information.

I would prefer to open a new activity or dialog. By the way, can you show me the easier way to do this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is my code.

```
Marker INFO=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(info)
    .title("TITLE")
    .snippet("SNIPPET")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)));
```

Comment: First of all you need to setup `Custom Info window` as per your requirement and then add `Intent` into `Handler` and implement Button onclick on this `Handler`

Comment: Check out the "MarkerDemoActivity" in the GoogleMap samples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I click a button (or something else) into the Infowindow to open a new activity (or a dialog) to show more information. Alternatively, I click a link into the Infowindow to open a webpage to show more information.

Neither of those are possible. However, [you can detect a click on the whole info window via `setOnInfoWindowClickListener()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#info_window_events). Your `onInfoWindowClick()` method of your `OnInfoWindowClickListener` can then call `startActivity()`, `show()` a `DialogFragment`, etc.